# Efficient way to print lines from a massive file using awk, sed, or something else?

Tags: sed, awk, performance

If I had a plain-text file containing 8 million lines and I want to print out lines 4,000,010 to 4,000,000 to the screen, which would be more efficient: awk or sed?

There is no pattern to the text, and unfortunately, a database isn't an option. I know this isn't ideal, I'm just curious on which one would complete the task quicker.

Or maybe there is even a better alternative to sed or awk?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither, use `tail` or `head` instead:

```
$ time tail -n 4000001 foo | head -n 11
real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time head -n 4000010 foo | tail -n 11
real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.036s
```

`tail` is in fact consistently faster. I ran both commands 100 times and calculated their average:

#### tail:

```
real    0.03962
user    0.02956
sys     0.01456
```

#### head:

```
real    0.06284
user    0.07356
sys     0.07244
```

I imagine `tail` is faster because though it has to seek all the way to line 4e10, it does not actually print anything until it gets there while `head` will print everything until line 4e10 + 10.

---

Compare to some other methods sorted in order of time:

#### sed:

```
$ time sed -n 4000000,4000011p;q foo
real    0m0.312s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m0.072s
```

#### Perl:

```
$ time perl -ne 'next if $.<4000000; print; exit if $.>=4000010' foo 
real    0m1.000s
user    0m0.936s
sys     0m0.064s
```

#### awk:

```
$ time awk '(NR>=4000000 && NR<=4000010){print} (NR==4000010){exit}' foo 
real    0m0.955s
user    0m0.868s
sys     0m0.080s
```

Basically, the rule is the less you parse, the faster you are. Treating the input as a stream of data which only needs to be printed to the screen (as `tail` does) will always be the fastest way.

Comment: Great! Works visibly faster than sed. Just out of curiosity however would you know the efficiency difference between sed/awk for the same task?

Comment: @KevinDuke make sure you use my updated version, there was a mistake in the first one. I will post some tests with other tools in a second but all of them will need to parse the lines somehow which should make them slower.

Comment: @KevinDuke comparisons added.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to doing it the other way around? I mean: `head -n 4000010 foo.txt | tail -n 10`? It seems the more intuitive way to do it to me, since it doesn't require you to know the exact length of the file. It should even be faster, since AFAIK `tail` has to read the *whole* file (in order to know how many lines there are), whereas `head` stops reading after the appropriate number of lines.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for spending the time to do all these tests, it is really interesting and useful.

Comment: @evilsoup see updated answer. `head` will be slower because it has to print unnecessary lines.

Comment: Adding a `NR>4000010{exit}` to the end of the awk or a `;4000011q` to the end of the sed function cuts the time down by almost half, largely because that allows the script to skip reading nearly half of the file.  But head | tail is still faster.

Comment: @dannysauer good points, thanks. Answer updated.

Comment: Your results are interesting.  On one of my slower systems, head | tail is consistently faster than tail | head (by close to 50%). :)  Goes to show that benchmarks need to be verified in a given environment before being relied upon absolutely. :D