# How can I get a specific line from a file?

Tags: files, text-processing

I want to extract an exact line from a very big file. For example, line 8000 would be gotten like this:

```
command -line 8000 > output_line_8000.txt
```

Comment: Many of the methods below are mentioned in this SO Q&A as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's already an answer with `perl` and `awk`. Here's a `sed` answer:

```
sed -n '8000{p;q}' file
```

The advantage of the `q` command is that `sed` will quit as soon as the 8000-th line is read (<strike>unlike the other `perl` and `awk` methods</strike> (it was changed after common creativity, haha)).

A pure Bash possibility (bash≥4):

```
mapfile -s 7999 -n 1 ary < file
printf '%s' "${ary[0]}"
```

This will slurp the content of `file` in an array `ary` (one line per field), but skip the first 7999 lines (`-s 7999`) and only read one line (`-n 1`).

Comment: _they changed it_: it's incorrect.  One changed it, after [another](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130725/36502) was posted.

Comment: Creative commons `:)`

Comment: @devnull edited accordingly `:)`

Comment: Actually more use of CC is evident.  `mapfile` variant didn't make it way, surprisingly `:)`.

Answer (score 9):

It's Saturday and I had nothing better to do so I tested some of these for speed. It turns out that the `sed`, `gawk` and `perl` approaches are basically equivalent. The head&tail one is the slowest but, suprisingly, the fastest *by an order of magnitude* is the pure bash one:

Here are my tests:

```
$ for i in {1..5000000}; do echo "This is line $i" >>file; done
```

The above creates a file with 50 million lines which occupies 100M.

```
$ for cmd in "sed -n '8000{p;q}' file" \
            "perl -ne 'print && exit if $. == 8000' file" \
            "awk 'FNR==8000 {print;exit}' file" 
            "head -n 8000 file | tail -n 1" \
            "mapfile -s 7999 -n 1 ary < file; printf '%s' \"${ary[0]}\"" \
            "tail -n 8001 file | head -n 1"; do 
    echo "$cmd"; for i in {1..100}; do
     (time eval "$cmd") 2>&1 | grep -oP 'real.*?m\K[\d\.]+'; done | 
        awk '{k+=$1}END{print k/100}'; 
    done
sed -n '8000{p;q}' file
0.04502
perl -ne 'print && exit if $. == 8000' file
0.04698
awk 'FNR==8000 {print;exit}' file
0.04647
head -n 8000 file | tail -n 1
0.06842
mapfile -s 7999 -n 1 ary < file; printf '%s' "This is line 8000
"
0.00137
tail -n 8001 file | head -n 1
0.0033
```

Comment: You missed `tail | head`, which was the best method in your benchmark [last time this came up](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94318/efficient-way-to-print-lines-from-a-massive-file-using-awk-sed-or-something-el/94320#94320) (bash's `mapfile` didn't come up that time).

Comment: @Gilles thanks added. The `mapfile` is still the fastest but just barely.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it many ways.

Using `perl`:

```
perl -nle 'print && exit if $. == 8000' file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==8000 {print;exit}' file
```

Or you can use `tail` and `head` to prevent from reading entire file until the 8000th line:

```
tail -n +8000 | head -n 1
```

Comment: Why `FNR` and not `NR`?

Comment: `FNR` for doing with multiple files.

Answer (score 4):

Another version with `tail` and `head`

```
head -n 8000 file | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -n '8000p;' filename
```

If the file is large, then it'd be better to quit:

```
sed -n '8000p;8001q' filename
```

You could similarly quit reading the entire file using `awk` or `perl` too:

```
awk 'NR==8000{print;exit}' filename
```

```
perl -ne 'print if $.==8000; last if $.==8000' filename
```

Comment: @Gnouc [cc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/130722/2)

Comment: @Gnouc If you want to hear that, __yes__.  You picked up early quitting from this one, and the head-tail variant from the [other one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130724/36502).  It's not unusual on SO.  All content is under [cc by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) anyways.  So nothing to complain.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ cat -n filename | grep -E "[ \t]+8000"
```

#### Example

```
$ cat -n /etc/abrt/plugins/CCpp.conf  | grep -E "^[ \t]+16"
    16  #DebuginfoLocation = /var/cache/abrt-di
```