# What's the fastest way to get n-th line of a text file

Tags: bash, text-processing

Given a file with m lines, how to get the n-th line. m can be smaller than n sometimes. I have tried:

```
method1: sed -ne '10p' file.txt
method2: sed -ne '10p' <file.txt
method3: sed -ne '10{p;q;}' file.txt
method4: awk 'NR==10' file.txt
```

in LeetCode's https://leetcode.com/problems/tenth-line/. method1 beats others. I don't know why. I think method3 should be faster.

Are there faster ways?

Updates:

Following @skwllsp suggestion, I run some commands. The results are:
instructions

```
instructions commands
428,160,537 perf stat sed -ne '10p' file.txt
427,426,310 perf stat sed -ne '10p' <file.txt
1,033,730   perf stat sed -ne '10{p;q;}' file.txt
1,111,502   perf stat awk 'NR == 10 { print ; exit ;} ' file.txt
```

method4 has changed according to @Archemar's answer

and

```
777,525 perf -stat tail -n +10 file.txt |head -n 1
```

which is much less than method1.

Comment: The link you have provided requires a subscription to see the stuff :/P

Comment: @sjsam: Sorry, I paste the result page url. I have chage it to the right one

Comment: If you feed `sed` a gigantic file, method 3 will likely stay roughly constant and method 1 will get progressively slower.  How big was the file you tested?

Comment: @Wildcard: There are 7 tests. It's a black box too me. The first test case has only 10 lines.

Comment: @frams : I believe the first and second method makes no difference. I have just started a thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855666/speed-difference-in-explicit-redirection). You may wanna stay updated with it.

Comment: @sjsam: Thank you very much! But after some tests, it appears that method1 took more time than method2 both on LeetCode and my Terminal.

Comment: @Archemar: useful link. Can it be improved with only one line to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's measure your tests to see how many instructions are done in each method. I created my own file  `seq 2000000 >  2000000.txt` and I want to find which method is the fastest.

---

```
$ perf stat sed -ne '10p' 2000000.txt 
10

 Performance counter stats for 'sed -ne 10p 2000000.txt':

        203.877247 task-clock                #    0.991 CPUs utilized          
                 5 context-switches          #    0.025 K/sec                  
                 3 cpu-migrations            #    0.015 K/sec                  
               214 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
       405,075,423 cycles                    #    1.987 GHz                     [50.20%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
       838,221,677 instructions              #    2.07  insns per cycle         [75.20%]
       203,113,013 branches                  #  996.251 M/sec                   [74.99%]
           766,918 branch-misses             #    0.38% of all branches         [75.16%]

       0.205683270 seconds time elapsed
```

So first method - 838,221,677 instructions.

---

```
$ perf stat sed -ne '10{p;q;}' 2000000.txt 
10

 Performance counter stats for 'sed -ne 10{p;q;} 2000000.txt':

          1.211558 task-clock                #    0.145 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.002 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               213 page-faults               #    0.176 M/sec                  
         1,633,950 cycles                    #    1.349 GHz                     [23.73%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
           824,789 instructions              #    0.50  insns per cycle        
           164,935 branches                  #  136.135 M/sec                  
            11,751 branch-misses             #    7.12% of all branches         [83.24%]

       0.008374725 seconds time elapsed
```

So, third method - 824,789 instructions. It is much better than the first method.

---

The improved forth method

```
$ perf stat awk 'NR == 10 { print ; exit ;} ' 2000000.txt 
10

 Performance counter stats for 'awk NR == 10 { print ; exit ;}  2000000.txt':

          1.357354 task-clock                #    0.162 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.001 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               282 page-faults               #    0.208 M/sec                  
         1,777,749 cycles                    #    1.310 GHz                     [11.54%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
           919,636 instructions              #    0.52  insns per cycle        
           185,695 branches                  #  136.807 M/sec                  
            11,218 branch-misses             #    6.04% of all branches         [91.64%]

       0.008375258 seconds time elapsed
```

Little bit worse than the second method. Anyway it is as efficient as the third method.

---

You might repeat the same tests with your file and see which method is the best.

---

A measument for the second method:

```
$ perf stat sed -ne '10p' <2000000.txt 
10

 Performance counter stats for 'sed -ne 10p':

        203.278584 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
                 1 context-switches          #    0.005 K/sec                  
                 3 cpu-migrations            #    0.015 K/sec                  
               213 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
       403,941,976 cycles                    #    1.987 GHz                     [49.84%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
       835,372,994 instructions              #    2.07  insns per cycle         [74.92%]
       203,327,145 branches                  # 1000.239 M/sec                   [74.90%]
           773,067 branch-misses             #    0.38% of all branches         [75.35%]

       0.203714402 seconds time elapsed
```

It is as bad as the first method

Comment: Please include the results of the second method too..

Comment: @sjsam: I updates the question too. I seems that command <file.txt and command file.txt are different. <file.txt is faster?

Comment: @skwllsp: nice! There should be a measure. I'll check out

Answer (score 0):

for awk

```
 awk 'NR == 10 { print ; exit ;} ' file.txt
```

I think perl is faster, there was a same question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94318/efficient-way-to-print-lines-from-a-massive-file-using-awk-sed-or-something-el?lq=1) about one year ago.

see also

1. [cat line X to line Y on a huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file?lq=1)
2. [How can I get a specific line from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130721/how-can-i-get-a-specific-line-from-a-file?lq=1)

Comment: It does save a lot of time for large files.